# Поведение оператора in в коллекциях

Tags: python, коллекции

Для понимания мотивации опишу контекст. Я реализую класс неориентированного графа, который выглядит упрощенно так

```py
class Edge(NamedTuple):
    s: str
    d: str

class Network:
    verts: set[str]
    edges: set[Edge]
```

Предполагается проводить над этим графом различные операции, которые включают в себя проверку вхождение некоторого ребра в множество ребер. Задача вполне тривиальная, но когда пишешь на пайтоне хочется лаконичности. Поэтому у меня встал следующий вопрос. Как можно добиться следующего результата:

```py
class Edge(NamedTuple):
    s: str
    d: str

e = Edge('A', 'B')
edges = {e,}
e2 = Edge('B', 'A')
assert e2 in edges # True
```

Вполне ясно, что можно наследовать класс множества и перегрузить метод _*contains*_, но может быть знатоки пайтона знают другие варианты?

Comment: Не могу гарантировать, что это хорошая идея, но можно на этапе создания объекта в `__init__` прописать, чтобы было `self.s <= self.d`. Если нам передают параметры, для которых это не выполняется, то поменять их местами.

Comment: Также должно быть достаточно переопределить методы `__eq__` и `__hash__`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493307/creating-set-of-objects-of-user-defined-class-in-python

Comment: @EzikBro оба варианта оказались рабочими и красивыми, спасибо, если оформите как ответ отмечу как решение